# Implementing async logger

Tags: c, asynchronous, logging

Is there an easy way in C to implement an async logger with an API like this?

Possible call:

```
log_info("name=%s, age=%d, some_ptr=%p ...", name, age, data);
```

It should be possible to use `printf`-formatting. The output / formatting is then not generated in the current thread, but just some piece of data is created which is stored in a ring buffer (or some other queue). So the actual logging is then done in another thread which is just reading this log-queue. E.g. formatting floating point numbers can be quite expensive and due to that I wan to avoid doing that in the current thread.

I know it's not trivial to implement this, because storing and restoring this `va_list` is not really possible. Also another tricky thing might be that string-parameters have to be copied, because they might get invalidated after some time.

Does an easy trick exist to serialize `va_list` and to deserialize it again in the writer thread? And maybe also to find out which argument is a string that has to be copied?

Comment: formatting floating point numbers is slow? You must be generating a huge number of log messages if this is an issue. You sure you need to create this complex system just to avoid %f

Comment: i mean doing the logging async because the IO is slow is certinaly a common thing to do, but you would build the message synchronously

Comment: The number of log messages is not that large, but the system is quite latency sensitive, so if possible the formatting of floating pointer numbers should also be outsourced. Unfortunately, formatting (and as well parsing) floats is not a cheap thing. Plus I'm curious if something like that is even possible.